# Question on how to interpret this recursion sum function answer? def sum_numbers(n): return n + sum_numbers(n-1) if n else 0

Tags: python, recursion

Question asked to sum first n natural numbers.

My answer is:

```py
def sum_numbers(x):
    
    if x == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return sum_numbers(x-1) + x
```

However, there is a more succinct:

```py
def sum_numbers(n):
  return n + sum_numbers(n-1) if n else 0
```

Was wondering how I should interpret the `sum_numbers(n-1) if n`? when does the `else 0` come into play and `n` stop holding true? Looking at my original answer it seems its trying to say that we recurse function  until `x==1` before we return the entire sum?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### The ternary operator

If you are familiar with other programming languages, python's `a if b else c` is expressed:

- `b ? a : c` in C and Java;
- `if b then a else c` in OCaml and Haskell.

`?:` is often called "the ternary operator", and the whole expression is called a "conditional expression" as opposed to the "conditional statement" you are familiar with.

In all cases, it is an expression that evaluates to the result of `a` or the result of `c` depending on the truth-value of `b`.

Inside a function, the two following fragments of code are equivalent:

```py
if b:
  return a
else:
  return c
```

```py
return (a if b else c)
```

Note that the expression is evaluated *lazily*, meaning that only the relevant subexpression is evaluated. For instance, the following code is correct and does not result in a ZeroDivisionError:

```py
x = 6
y = 0
z = ((x / y) if (y != 0) else (x / 2))
print(z)
```

Output: `3`.

### Converting between `int` and `bool`

The condition used in the conditional statement `n + sum_numbers(n-1) if n else 0` is simply "`n`". This might be unexpected, because `n` is a number, not a condition, right?

There is a python feature that any value can be used as a condition. This includes numbers, lists, dicts, strings, etc. In that case, "zero" or "empty" values mean `false`, and "nonzero" or "non-empty" values mean `true`. Since `n` is a number, `"n`" is the same as "`n != 0`" as the condition here.

### Conclusion

Finally, the given piece of code is equivalent to:

```py
def sum_numbers(n):
  if n != 0:
    return n + sum_numbers(n-1)
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Thank you separating it makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of: `return n + sum_numbers(n-1) if n else 0` is this:

First split off two expressions: `n + sum_numbers(n-1)` and `0` because the `if else` should be interpreted as:

`<expr1> if <cond> else <expr2>`

This leaves `<cond>` above which is `n` in your expression. This is using `n` as the conditional, which means `bool(n)`, which in the case of an integer means it returns `False` if `0` otherwise `True`.

So your expression means return `n + sum_numbers(n-1)` if `n` is `truthy` (ie non-zero) else return `0`.

Note that the evaluation of `n` as a `bool` is performed before either of the other two expressions.

So the second `sum_numbers` is really returning the sum of `0..n`